# asp.net retain list values between postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, postback

Hello everybody and thanks in advance,

I've made a class in my .cs file and then declared a list<> of it like this...

```
    public partial class MyClass : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public List<PrecioStock> PreciosYStocks = new List<PrecioStock>();


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
...
...

    public class PrecioStock
    {
        public string Precio;
        public string Stock;

        public PrecioStock(string Precio, string Stock)
        {
            this.Precio = Precio;
            this.Stock = Stock;
        }

        public void SetPrecio(string nuevoPrecio)
        {
            this.Precio = nuevoPrecio;
        }

        public void SetStock(string nuevoStock)
        {
            this.Stock = nuevoStock;
        }

        public string GetPrecio()
        {
            return this.Precio;
        }

        public string GetStock()
        {
            return this.Stock;
        }

    }
```

Then, I fill it this way, with some textboxes' texts...

```
            PreciosYStocks.Clear();

            foreach (ListItem items in ControlListaGenerico.Items)
            {
                if (items.Selected)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < TablaDeDatos.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if(items.Value.Equals(TablaDeDatos.Rows[i]["ID_FORMATO"].ToString()))
                        {
                            TextBox Precio = (TextBox)Precio_Stock_PN.FindControl("NuevoPrecioTB_" + items.Value);
                            Precio.Text = TablaDeDatos.Rows[i]["PRECIO"].ToString();

                            TextBox Stock = (TextBox)Precio_Stock_PN.FindControl("NuevoStockTB_" + items.Value);
                            Stock.Text = TablaDeDatos.Rows[i]["STOCK"].ToString();

                            PreciosYStocks.Add(new PrecioStock(Precio.Text, Stock.Text));

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Well, it seems to fill well, but the problem is that when I click the UPDATE button of the DetailsView, this generates a postback event, the data is lost and I'm not be able to access to it anymore.

So, how can I access to it after postback? I mean, make it persistent.

I've read about "viewState" and "Session" ways but don't know how to implement them, in case they are the answer to this.

Please, help and thanks again.

Comment: If they are per user then Session is the way to go. You'll find information on that with a quick search. If they are global for all users then they should be in the Application object for all to access, or static in this class if not needed elsewhere.

Comment: @Mazinger What have you exactly tried with [viewstate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx) and [sessionstate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb.aspx) that didn't work?

Comment: Hi Eugene, the thing is that I don't know how to use them in my list: inside the class definition?, in the get and set methods?, when I add elements to the list? I'm confused about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data isn't too huge (in your case it's not a lot of data) then you can write it to the page's `ViewState`. That way it gets submitted back with each postback. If you store it in `Session` then you end up with lots of data stored in `Session` that might never be needed again.

Here's the pattern.

- Create a class that represents whatever data you need to store. (You could have more than one but one is simpler.)
- Store whatever you need to persist in that class.
- In the `PreRender` event when the modifications to the page are done, you write your class to `ViewState`.
- In the `Load` event you read it back. If there's nothing to read (it's the first page load) then you create a new instance of your class.

  ```
  public partial class YourPage: System.Web.UI.Page
  {
      private PageState _pageState;

      protected void Page_Load(object source, EventArgs e)
      {
          _pageState = ViewState["pageState"] as PageState ?? new PageState();
      }

      protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          ViewState["pageState"] = _pageState;
      }
  }

  [Serializable]
  public class PageState
  {
      //Whatever data you need to persist
  }
  ```